# 2 arrays with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a register to arrange students grades by name and grade. I want two arrays, one with names and one with the grades.

Names:

["Klara", "Andrea", "Emil", "Sarah", "Alicia", "Victor", "Thomas", "Robert"]

Grades:

["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C", "E", "E”].

I want to use the function (getGrade) that searches for a name and then responds by showing the grade (the first matching name).

I also  want to create a function (getNames) that will list all the names in the form of an array with a certain grade.

Can anyone show me how to do this please? Any help would be much appreciated!

I now have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Javascript och funktioner Uppgift 10</title>
    <script>


var names = {
"Klara": "A",
"Andrea": "B",
"Emil": "C",
"Sarah": "A",
"Alicia": "D"
"Victor": "C",
"Thomas": "E",
"Robert": "E"
};

function getGrade(name) {
return names[name];
}

function getName(grade) {
var students = [];
for (var name in names) {
    if (names[name] == grade) {
        students.push(name);
    }   
}
return students;
}

console.log(getGrade("Klara")); // A
console.log(getName("A")) //["Klara", "Sarah"]

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Uppgift 10</h1>
    <form name = "f1">
    Enter Grade<input type ="text" id="grades" name="wed" value="" /><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Check Student" onclick="getNames()" />
    </form>
    <div id="text" />

</body>
```

but how do I connect the button to the the actual code. So that I can type in the grade, press the button and then get the names with that grade?

Comment: Try using Array.indexOf() method : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp
For getNames you can iterate while indexOf() is greater than -1, and set the second parameter to current index.

Comment: This just screams homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your arrays are defined like this:

```
var names = ["Klara", "Andrea", "Emil", "Sarah", "Alicia", "Victor", "Thomas", "Robert"];
var grades = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C", "E", "E”];
```

The `getGrade` function should look something like this:

```
function getGrade(name) {
    return grades[names.indexOf(name)];
}
```

Documentation for the [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function.

The `getNames` function should look something like this:

```
function getNames(grade) {
    var namesWithGrade = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        if (grades[i] === grade) {
            namesWithGrade.push(names[i]);
        }
    }
    return namesWithGrade;
}
```

Documentation for [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a life saver. How do I add that to my body? connect it to the button? 
 <body>
 
  <h1>Studenters Betyg</h1>
  <form name = "f1">
  Enter Grade<input type ="text" id="grades" name="wed" value="" /><br/>
     <input type="button" value="Check Student" onclick="getNames()" />
  </form>
  <div id="text" />
  
 </body>

</html>

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You can ask another question here about doing that, however, it is not constructive to cary out a lengthy conversation in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can just use a dictionary to contain the grades.

```
var names = {
    "David": "A",
    "Paul": "C",
    "Laura": "B",
    "Joe": "D",
    "Kevin": "A"
};

function getGrade(name) {
    return names[name];
}

function getName(grade) {
    var students = [];
    for (var name in names) {
        if (names[name] == grade) {
            students.push(name);
        }   
    }
    return students;
}

console.log(getGrade("David")); // A
console.log(getName("A")) //["David", "Kevin"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much David! How do I connect it to some sort of blank space and button. I need to write the the grade and then click a button that will then give me the name of the person with that grade. Thank you again for your help!!